# Enabling button after scroll to the bottom

Tags: angularjs, scroll, modal-dialog, addeventlistener, pdf.js

Basically what I want to do is after user scrolls pdf file that is in the modal (kinda like pop-up) the button on the bottom of the modal should became active.

EDIT:

The main problem was that the size of pdf I was uploading is varying (users are able to upload it to the system), so I could not define the exact height of it. Also I had to use pdfjs to upload the file so it caused few more issues (apparently it is not possible to add scroll event to the very pdf (https://github.com/pipwerks/PDFObject/issues/58#event-603169061).)

So after some trials and errors here is how I did it:

1. Downloaded pdfjs https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/ (cool thing). 
   Here's some more info about it - https://developer.tizen.org/community/tip-tech/displaying-pdf-files-pdf.js-library
2. Rendered my pdf one by one page, added pages to existing element on which added the scroll event and found out the height of pdf file by multiplying no of pages by the height of one page:

```js
    PDFJS.getDocument('some/pdf.pdf').promise.then(function(pdf) {
        thePdf = pdf;
        var viewer = angular.element(document.querySelector('#pdf-scroller') );

        for(var page = 1; page <= pdf.numPages; page++) {
          var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
          canvas.className = 'pdf-page-canvas';
          viewer.append(canvas);
          renderPage(page, canvas);
        }
    });

    function renderPage(pageNumber, canvas) {
        thePdf.getPage(pageNumber).then(function(page) {
          var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);
          canvas.height = viewport.height;
          canvas.width = viewport.width;
          page.render({canvasContext: canvas.getContext('2d'), viewport: viewport});
    });
  }

    angular.element(document.querySelector('#pdf-scroller') ).bind('scroll', function(){

        var wrapper = angular.element(document.querySelector('#pdf-scroller') );
        var agreementTextElement = document.getElementsByClassName('pdf-page-canvas')[0]
        var pagesNo = document.getElementsByClassName('pdf-page-canvas').length
        var totalDocumentHeight = agreementTextElement.offsetHeight * pagesNo;

        if (this.scrollTop >= ((totalDocumentHeight) - wrapper.context.offsetHeight)){
            document.getElementById('closeButton').removeAttribute('disabled')
        }
  })
```

Comment: Please re-organize your question. You should only put working code in `code-snippets`.

Answer (score 1):

I add `id="pdf-wrapper` on the parent `<div>` of `<object>`, the overflow of div will be see on scroll and give the height of div to 600px while pdf is 1000px

then put the scroll event listener to pdf-wrapper

when scrolling in div#pdf-wrapper to the bottom of content, the scrollTop is 400px (1000px - 600px), so I compare the wrapper.scrollTop with agreementTextElement.offsetHeight - wrapper.offsetHeight

**Edit1:**

If you would like to use `body` for scrolling then use `document.addEventListener('scroll',function(){})` and compare the body scrolling with pdf height minus the height of the window then enable the button

**Edit2:**

give the modal's height to 80vh then add event listener on it

**Edit3**

back to edit1 solution but change from get pdf id to query selector by class name

[image]

the example code is below

```js
var pdf = document.querySelectorAll('.pdf')
document.addEventListener('scroll',function(){
    var agreementTextElement = document.getElementById('uniqueTCid')
    if (document.body.scrollTop >= pdf[0].offsetHeight - window.innerHeight){
        console.log('remove disabled attribute from button')
        document.getElementById('closeButton').removeAttribute('disabled')
    }
  })
```

```html
<div id="pdf-modal" class="modal-body">
    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <object class="pdf" data='someInfo.pdf'
                type='application/pdf'
                style="background: #999; height: 1000px;">
        </object>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="text-align: right;">
        <button id="closeButton" class="button button-blue" data-ng-click="closeThisDialog(true)" disabled>
        click to close
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: thank you! It helped a bit but the problem is that now I am able to scroll both pdf in <object> and parent <div> of it (there are two scrolls) - so the user mus scroll not the very pdf but that <div> to enable button. Because I am uploading pdf not from the web but directly from code director. So what I will probably do is set the height of pdf to be greater or equal to <div> height so there will be just one scroll

Comment: @cinnamon I edited my answer. not sure if it's what you're looking for :/ please try :)

Comment: It is not working this way :/ may it be because my pdf is loaded on modal on actual page? So eventListener is not adding to 'document?'

Comment: So basically document.addEventListener('scroll',function() ) adds eventListener to the page that modal is showing on but not to the modal itself

Comment: @cinnamon So, you mean by scroll modal to the bottom of the pdf then the button become disable. am I right? if yes, then how about fix the height of modal to 80vh and overflow-y: scroll; after that add event listener to the modal :)

Comment: still two scrolls as before and still need to adjust the height of <object> manually in the later case.
is it possible to set eventListener to the very <object>? Since it is the one I would like to be scrolling? (the pdf from data in <object> element)

Comment: @cinnamon then I suggest back to the edit1. put the eventListener to document itself because if we won't give the height to parent of pdf <object> then the scroll is on body. if we want to scroll the pdf, we need to do it on a wrapper of it (as far as my knowledge), in this case, document.body or parent <div> (if parent has specific height). (edited code in the snippet but the eventListener is on document)

Comment: event is still set on the background page and after scrolling to the bottom button is not enabled. and btw - my modal is smaller than the pdf (i.e. ~300px x 300px)
I have tried doing similiar fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ht9u7bgt/75/